# Vertical skip after the hline

Tags: spacing

I have a problem with my table. Basically, I would like to leave a medium skip after the `hline` before the name of the models (i.e. after the line and before 1. Female).

I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\footnotesize{
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{\textbf{Sensitivity Analysis II}\label{table5}} 
\begin{tabular}{l*{5}{c}}
\hline\hline 
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Fst Stage}}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Snd Stage}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{LL}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{$\rho$=0}} \smallskip \\
 &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Lagged SF}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{SF}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Fairness}}& &\\
 &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{(Country Level)}}&&&&\\
\hline \medskip
1. Female &0.012***& 0.009***& 0.1999***&3,504.223& -0.053***\\
2. Male \medskip\\ 
3. Europe\\
4. Africa\\
5. Asia\\
6. North America\\
7. South America\\ 
8. Others \medskip \\
9. Left-Oriented\\ 
10. Right-Oriented \medskip \\ 
11. Competition is bad\\ 
12. Competition is good \medskip \\ 
13. Married \\
14. Single\medskip \\ 
15. Turst Others\\
16. No Trust Others \smallskip\\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\footnotesize * \(p<0.10\), ** \(p<0.05\), *** \(p<0.01\)}\\
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses}\\
\end{tabular}}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Apparently it does not work. No matter where I try to put that skip (before or after hline or after `&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{(Country Level)}}&&&&\\)` I cannot leave any skip after the `hline`.

Comment: how about `\hline \medskip \\`?

Comment: Nothing happens. Still I cannot introduce the medskip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some improvements and a simplification of the code of your table. The row numbers are automated and `right-aligned`, emulating  an `enumerate` environment, so that the text in the first column is always left-aligned. I also used `booktabs`, which makes some vertical padding around horizontal lines in tables, and defines an adjustable `\addlinespace` command , that allows easily separating groups of rows. Last, the `makecell` package allows for line breaks inside cells, and a common formatting of column/row heads.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{caption, booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\captionsetup{font=bf}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
  \newcounter{rownum}\setcounter{rownum}{0}
  \setlength\defaultaddspace{1.25ex}
  \centering
  \footnotesize{
    \def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
    \caption{Sensitivity Analysis II}\label{table5}
    \begin{tabular}{>{\refstepcounter{rownum}\eqmakebox[R][r]{\therownum.}\hskip\labelsep}l*{5}{c}}
      \toprule\midrule
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{}& \textbf{1\textsuperscript{st} Stage} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{2\textsuperscript{nd} Stage}}& \textbf{LL}& \boldmath$ \rho=0 $ \\
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \thead{Lagged SF & & & & \\(Country Level)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{SF}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Fairness}}& &\\
      \cmidrule(lr){1-6}
      \addlinespace
      Female & 0.012*** & 0.009*** & 0.1999*** & 3,504.223 & -0.053*** \\
      Male\\
      \addlinespace
      Europe\\
      Africa\\
      Asia\\
      North America\\
      South America\\
      Others\\
      \addlinespace
      Left-Oriented\\
      Right-Oriented\\
      \addlinespace
      Competition is bad\\
      Competition is good\\
      \addlinespace
      Married \\
      Single\\
      \addlinespace
      Trust Others\\
      No Trust Others\\
      \midrule\bottomrule
      \addlinespace
      \multicolumn{6}{l}{\footnotesize * \(p<0.10\),\quad ** \(p<0.05\),\quad *** \(p<0.01\)}\\
      \multicolumn{6}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses}\\
    \end{tabular}}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\noalign`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l*{5}{c}}
\hline\hline
blb\\
\hline\noalign{\medskip}
1. Female &0.012***& 0.009***& 0.1999***&3,504.223& -0.053***\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you guys. Sorted. Both ways solve my problem. Dario

Answer (score 1):

Adding a couple of `\\`seems to introduce some space. You can add `medskip`, or `vspace{<length>}`or other vertical spaces also, even negative.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\footnotesize{
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{\textbf{Sensitivity Analysis II}\label{table5}} 
\begin{tabular}{l*{5}{c}}
\hline\hline \\
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Fst Stage}}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Snd Stage}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{LL}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{$\rho$=0}} \smallskip \\
 &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Lagged SF}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{SF}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Fairness}}& &\\
 &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{(Country Level)}}&&&&\medskip\\
\hline  \\
1. Female &0.012***& 0.009***& 0.1999***&3,504.223& -0.053***\\
2. Male \\ 
3. Europe\\
4. Africa\\
5. Asia\\
6. North America\\
7. South America\\ 
8. Others \medskip\\
9. Left-Oriented\\ 
10. Right-Oriented \medskip \\ 
11. Competition is bad\\ 
12. Competition is good \medskip \\ 
13. Married \\
14. Single\medskip \\ 
15. Turst Others\\
16. No Trust Others \smallskip\\
\hline\hline\\
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\footnotesize * \(p<0.10\), ** \(p<0.05\), *** \(p<0.01\)}\\
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses}\\
\end{tabular}}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image: Rotated table]